# User CALs on Windows Server 2008 R2 with EC2

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2 on EC2.  Per Amazon, the server license is included in my fees to them.

I have five users that will use Remote Desktop Services so I know I need 5 RDS CALs.

Do I also need 5 Windows Server 2008 R2 User/Device CALs?

Comment: Are you certain that you need additional CALs? Normally 5 of them are included in Windows 2008.

Comment: TS CALs are separate from the "core" CALs that ship with Windows.

Comment: @Valentin SPLA licenses (which is what Amazon is using) don't include CALs.  Only retain licenses include CALs.

Answer (score 0):

If your users already have Windows 2008 R2 CALs for within your office than you are covered.  If you don't have any Windows 2008 R2 servers within your office, and you don't have any Windows 2008 R2 CALs, and if Amazon doesn't include CALs in their offering, then technically you would need to purchase the Windows 2008 R2 CALs as well as the TS CALs.